# Web2py: Pass a variable from view to controller

Tags: javascript, python, web2py

How can I pass a JavaScript variable from the view to Python in controller? I don't want to use `request.vars` or `request.args`, because that would allow to user to give arbitrary parameters for the action by typing it into the address bar.

Example view:

```
<button onclick='myFunction();'>Execute</button>
<script>
    function myFunction();{
        var value = calculateValue();
        //pass value to my_action
        window.location = 'my_action';
    }
</script>
```

Example controller:

```
def index():
    return dict()

def my_action():
    #retrieve passed variable
    #handle the variable 
    #...
    redirect(URL('index'))
```

Comment: look into `args` and `vars`. They are used to pass variable and arguments  from URL to controller.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, it would allow the user to type something like this into address bar: `.../default/my_action/50` to give my_action a parameter of 50.

Comment: the other way to do it would be creating a session via an ajax call then redirecting to your `my_action` page which read that session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make an Ajax call:

```
<script>
    function myFunction();{
        var value = calculateValue();
        ajax('{{=URL('default', 'my_action')}}' + '?value=' + value, [], ':eval');
    }
</script>
```

Followed by a client-side redirect once the Ajax response is returned:

```
def my_action():
    value = request.vars.value
    # handle the variable 
    redirect(URL('index'), client_side=True)
```

Note, however, that even with this method, someone could still make a manual request to `/default/my_action?value=some_value` to send arbitrary data to your function (of course, they would have to be a little more technically savvy to do so, as the above URL would never appear in the browser address bar for them to observe -- they would have to inspect your code or watch the network traffic to figure out what request to make).

In general, if you are calculating a value in the browser and then submitting it to the server via an HTTP request, there is no way to prevent a knowledgeable attacker from submitting some arbitrary data rather than the value calculated by your Javascript code. Your best bet is to instead focus on doing some server-side validation of the input data, or move the calculation to the server (though presumably the calculation is based on some input that must ultimately come from the browser and therefore be validated in some way).

Comment: What does this do? `client_side=True`

Comment: Normally, when the `redirect()` function is called, it sends a 303 response to the browser instructing it to fetch a new URL. However, if you want the parent page to be replaced in the browser, a 303 response to an Ajax request won't help, as it will simply result in another Ajax request to the new URL. With `client_side=True`, `redirect` will instead send a special response header back to the browser where Javascript will detect the header and force a new URL to load in the window/tab. So, the redirect is happening client-side (via Javascript) rather than server-side (via a 303 response).

Comment: when I run my code... I get a 404 not found... I have added in the controller a definition for the function name "my_action" that doesn't return anything... any suggestions?

Comment: No suggestions without seeing your code. You probably need to create a new question with more details.

Comment: @Anthony shouldn't the ajax request be `ajax('{{=URL('default', 'my_action')}}'' + '?value=' + value, [], ':eval');` ?