# Web2py: Get value from client (view) to controller

Tags: web2py

I thought that I found the answer to my question in
[Web2py: Pass a variable from view to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107617/web2py-pass-a-variable-from-view-to-controller/43391943#43391943)

I'm trying to adopt the example there in order to get the size a DIV, which finally depends on the size of the browser window (defined relatively). To do so I have the following code in the view

```
<script>
    var div_size_Value = document.getElementById("model_graph_div").clientWidth;
    ajax('{{=URL('default', 'my_action', vars=dict(div_size_value=div_size_value))}}', [], ':eval');
</script>
```

But I always get

> NameError: name 'div_size_value' is not defined

The error seems to be okay, since the Javascript var div_size_value is addressed within the HTML Helper URL.

Thus my question is:
How can I get the DIV size value from the client (view) to a controller?

Thanks a lot for any support!

Best regards
Clemens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ajax('{{=URL('default', 'my_action', vars=dict(div_size_value=div_size_value))}}',
     [], ':eval');
```

You are mixing Javascript with Python. In a web2py template, everything inside the `{{...}}` template delimiters is Python code that gets executed on the server before sending the HTML to the browser. So, in your code, `div_size_value` is expected to be a Python variable available in the server-side Python environment. Because the URL query string involves a Javascript variable, you must instead build the query string via Javascript, as below:

```
ajax('{{=URL('default', 'my_action')}}' + '?div_size_value=' + div_size_value, ...)
```

Comment: Anthony, as always the solution ... thanks!

I'm little proud, that I have already seen the problem, that the HTML helper can not solve the Javascript variable. But I'm a little disappointed, that I didn't came to the solution by myself ;-)

Thanks for your patience with my questions. I promise to get better every line of web2py code ...

I wish you Happy Easter!

Best Regards
Clemens

Comment: Anthony, do you see an option to post the JS variable directly to a component load via {{=LOAD(...)}} since there is some more logic like user_signature, timeout etc.? If this would be possible the solution would be quite easier.

Best regards
Clemens

Comment: You can always load (or re-load) a component via Javascript using `jQuery.web2py.component(url, target, timeout, times)`, (with the `timeout` and `times` arguments being optional).

Comment: Anthony, I'm sorry, but I don't get it how to implement the component load via JS. My original LOAD is as follows:

`{{=LOAD('default','model.load',
                vars=dict(subscriber_uuid=subscriber_uuid,
                            model_uuid=model_uuid,
                            org='True', data='True', sys='True'),
            target='model_graph_div', ajax=True, content='', user_signature=True)}}`

How would this component load be scripted in JS, especially the user_signature argument?

Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: Use the `URL()` function with `user_signature=True` to generate the URL to be used in the JS code. If you need more details, you should probably create a new question.